# Hawtio gives NoModificationAllowedError on clicking on various options in the page

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio

Hawtio is throwing NoModificationAllowedError on clicking on various options in the hawtio - Apache Camel.

One such instance is by clicking on, Camel->Camel Contexts->Routes -> "myRoute" -> Then click on Route diagram option.

Could someone please give your inputs. Please find below the link to snapshots,

[Snapshot 1 - NoModificationAllowedError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGVYx.png)

[Snapshot 2 - Log console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfnX6.png)

Comment: Can you post a snapshot ? Also is it possible to post the log when you get this error ?

Comment: gnanagurus, Have attached the snapshots. Could you please have a look.

Comment: You need to tell versions of Camel, hawtio, app server used etc.